# how to remove default message error of zod

Tags: javascript, zod, mantine

How remove default error message if I don't pass the validation message parameter, it shows a standard error message, I'm using UI KIT MANTINE

```js
const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1),
  email: z.string().min(1),
  lastname: z.string().min(1)
})
```

Comment: Not really sure what mantine has to do with this?

Comment: because I'm using zod to validate a form made with mantine

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show any error, for some reason, just put an empty string as the message.

```js
const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1, ""),
  email: z.string().min(1, ""),
  lastname: z.string().min(1, "")
})
```